# Error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, vite

When I using vite + vue to do the unit testing for web components, I met this error:

> Error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. You may need to install appropriate plugins to handle the .html file format.
> ❯ formatError node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:38663:46
> ❯ TransformContext.error node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:38659:19
> ❯ TransformContext.transform node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:56777:22
> ❯ async Object.transform node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:38900:30
> ❯ async doTransform node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:55857:29

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It appears here that the HTML part of the file is being treated as javascript, meaning Vue does not recognize this HTML.

In my case error was because I named one Component as *.Vue (capital V) and not as *.vue.

```
import MyComp from "@/components/MyComp.Vue"; //This does not work.
```

I had to change the file name to .vue and the import statement to get it working.
I also restarted the server (just in case)

```
 import MyComp from "@/components/MyComp.vue"; //This does work with same file name.
```

This may be because .Vue files are treated as normal js files (not as components).. just a guess, I am new to Vue.